# Sentry - Docker containers network connect?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, containers, sentry

I installed Sentry on my network docker compose.

```yaml
version: "3"

networks:
  app: null

services:
  php:
    image: php:latest
    container_name: php
    expose:
      - 9000
    volumes:
      - ./httpdocs:/var/httpdocs
    networks:
      - app
    env_file: .env
  sentry:
    image: sentry:latest
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: sentry
    ports:
      - "9090:9000"
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - './data/sentry/sentry:/var/lib/sentry/files'
    networks:
      - app
```

there is too an apache container.
I set sentry and can access to the interface.

I installed Laravel in my httpdocs folder and try to catch error on Laravel
I set the .env with `SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN="http://c9ad8cf51cf04987f7817a38357a89d@localhost:9090/1"`

but i can't catch error.

I tried to add

```yaml
networks:
  default:
    name: "app"
```

found on forum but that's not working.

when i'm running `php artisan sentry:test`, i have this error

```yaml
DSN discovered from Laravel config or `.env` file!
Sending test event...
There was an error sending the event.
Please check if your DSN is set properly in your `.env` as `SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN` or in your config file `config/sentry.php`.
```

When running curl on container bin/bash

```
curl http://c9ad8cf51cf04987f7817a38357a89d@localhost:9090/1
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9090: Connection refused
```

I tried with urls `http://c9ad8cf51cf04987f7817a38357a89d@sentry:9090/1`, not working too

Is someone having any idea why i can't catch error ?

thanks.